# Swift - API returns array that contains different types

Tags: swift

I wanted to use the movie db API to search for movies, shows and actors.

But I encountered the following issue.
When I make the API call, as a response I could get back either of the mentioned 3 types in the same results array.

I don't really know how to deal with that. At first I thought I'd add a new enum to the results struct like so:

```
struct MultiSearchResults: Decodable {
    
    let page: Int
    let results: [Result]
    let total_results: Int
    let total_pages: Int
    
    enum Result: Decodable {
        case movie(Movie)
        case show(Show)
        case person(Person)
        
// Another idea that also did not work
//        var id: Int {
//            switch self {
//                case .Movie(let movie):
//                    return movie.id
//
//                case .Show(let show):
//                    return show.id
//
//                case .Person(let person):
//                    return person.id
//            }
//        }
    }
}
```

It's also worth to mention that I want to render that array (so each result has to be Identifiable).

So maybe a good idea would be to, I don't know, filter those results and create 3 different arrays?

Or maybe there is a way to render array items that do not conform to Identifiable.

I'm really new to swift and really don't know what would be the best solution here.

Comment: How does the API distinguish between the 3 kinds of objects?

Comment: The API adds media_type property, which is one of the three kinds

Comment: how does the JSON look?

Comment: Here https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/search/multi-search

Comment: IMO easiest is to treat it as array of ONE type - something like `struct Result`, which contains field that identifies its type (from `media_type`). That field can be `enum MediaType`.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how you would create that struct?

Answer (score 0):

For just 2 or 3 cases you can use nested `do ... try ... catch` to try decoding the first case, and if it fails try the next type.  For any more than 2 or 3 possibles it gets messy and you'd need to iterate through .allCases of the enum.

```
do {
     let movie = try container.decode(Movie.self, forKey: .results)
     results.append( .Movie(movie))
} catch {
   do {
      let show = try container.decode(Show.self, forKey: .result)
      results.append( .Show(show))
   } catch {
       do {
           let person = try container.decode(Person.self, forKey: .result 
           results.append( .Person(person))
       } catch {
          throw someKindOfError
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: And how would you modify my main struct?

Comment: You can use `if let movie = try container.tryDecode(Movie.self, ...) {}` to remove the need for this nesting. But in this case, OP has atag that he can switch on, instad.

Comment: @Alexander Potentially slightly less efficient as it will test every case, but I agree far easier to read. I couldn't see anything in the data to switch on, especially if the array is heterogenous.

Comment: @DamianKociszewski This would go in the `init(from decoder: Decoder)` implementation of your struct.

Comment: @flanker oops, I meant `try?`. Yeah, it's not ideal if there's a large number of cases. Though I'm less concerned about the performance, than I am the correctness. It's possible that one of the models has a subset of the properties of another model, allowing it to be initialized without issue, but erroneously in a case where the other model should have been used.